# how to load an image on a Qt Designer Form

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I am trying to Load an image on a Qt Designer form. I have written the code that displays a fine image in a new window after loading but when I am trying to display the same image on a form designed in Qt Designer it does not display an image on that, neither it is giving any error. Below is the code of the Qt form and the main class that it calls.

**Main file :**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
""" imageProc is an application to do several simple operations in image processing"""

from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
#from gui1 import *
import sip
from form import *
from form1 import *
from process import *


class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
 def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__()
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
    self.u=U_Form()
    self.u.setupUi(self)
    self.imgProc = imagePreProcessor()
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.u.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.load)
 def load(self):
    filepath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        self, 'Open File', '', 'All Files (*.*);;jpeg (*.jpeg);;jpg (*.jpg);;png (*.png);;ppm (*.ppm)')
    filename=filepath.toLocal8Bit().data()
    if filepath:
        self.open(filepath)

 def open(self, filepath):
    self.form1= Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy1()
    self.form1.setupUi(self)
    self.form1.imgPreProc.loadImage(str(filepath))
    self.form1.prnt()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form=MyForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**form file :**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'form1.ui'
#
# Created: Sat Aug 23 03:10:41 2014
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import Image, ImageQt
from process import imagePreProcessor
import sip

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy1(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy1, self).__init__()
        self.imgPreProc = imagePreProcessor()
        #self.rightbottom = QtGui.QWidget(mainWidget)
        #self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        #self.setupUi(self)
    def setupUi(self, DiabeticRetinopathy):
        #mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        #hbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(mainWidget)
        #self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        #self.rightbottom = QtGui.QWidget(mainWidget)
        #self.label.setLayout(grid)
        DiabeticRetinopathy.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("DiabeticRetinopathy"))
        DiabeticRetinopathy.resize(640, 480)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../im0003.jpg")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        DiabeticRetinopathy.setWindowIcon(icon)
        DiabeticRetinopathy.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(0, 86, 86);"))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(DiabeticRetinopathy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 80, 181, 131))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayoutWidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"Verdana\";"))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"Verdana\";"))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"Verdana\";"))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"Verdana\";"))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 250, 182, 141))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayoutWidget_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setMargin(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"Verdana\";"))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_5"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"Verdana\";"))
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_6"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"Verdana\";"))
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_7"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"Verdana\";"))
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_8"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_8)
        DiabeticRetinopathy.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(DiabeticRetinopathy)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        DiabeticRetinopathy.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(DiabeticRetinopathy)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(DiabeticRetinopathy)

    def retranslateUi(self, DiabeticRetinopathy):
        DiabeticRetinopathy.setWindowTitle(_translate("DiabeticRetinopathy", "Diabetic Retinopathy Detection", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("DiabeticRetinopathy", "Grayscale", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("DiabeticRetinopathy", "Zero Padding", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("DiabeticRetinopathy", "Normalize", None))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("DiabeticRetinopathy", "Smoothing", None))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("DiabeticRetinopathy", "Detection of Micro-Aneurysms", None))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("DiabeticRetinopathy", "Detection of Hemorrhages", None))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("DiabeticRetinopathy", "Detection of Exudates", None))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("DiabeticRetinopathy", "Grading", None))
    def prnt(self):
       self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
       self.label.setPixmap(self.imgPreProc.pixmap)
       x, y, w, h = 10, 10, 700, 605
       self.label.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)
       self.label.resize(w, h)
```

**LOAD IMAGE :**

```
class imagePreProcessor():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Qimg = None
        self.img = None
        self.image=QImage()

    def loadImage(self, imgFile):
      self.img = cv2.imread(imgFile)
      #cv2.imshow('image',self.img)
      #def toQimage(self):
      if self.img != None:
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(imgFile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your set parent of `QLabel` image is wrong. To fix them please set **true** parent `QWidget`;

```
def prnt(self):
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setPixmap(self.imgPreProc.pixmap)
    x, y, w, h = 10, 10, 700, 605
    self.label.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)
    self.label.resize(w, h)
```

Comment: ..thanks for your reply but i am working on an application where i need to browse an image from computer.this seems to be working  only for the particular image. i need to make the image path dynamic.can you give me some idea how can i do that?

Comment: I sorry, I mistake your question. Please see my last edited answer.